# Delete entries that have a dash in them in laravel

Tags: sql, postgresql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am writing a "run once, throw away" laravel task that is suppose to do a select on a table and remove any entry that contains a dash in the name.

```
A-R00001
B-R00001
C-R00001
UUA-F4
```

The above is the Example of some entries.

I know I could do something like: Model::where('name', 'like %-%')->delete();

I am wondering if this is the correct approach. Its running on a postgres database, not that, that should matter.

other answers I have seen use crazy regex and I dont think I need that in this case ...

**Ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is probably correct approach if you want to remove rows, but you should use:

```
Model::where('name', 'LIKE', '%-%')->delete();
```

instead of:

```
Model::where('name', 'like %-%')->delete();
```

Of course the question is, if you need to run any extra task for each row you delete. If so, you should first get the rows you want to delete and run extra tasks for them

**EDIT**

If you want to use Laravel events to do extra tasks, you cannot simple delete all rows.

You need to run:

```
$models = Model::where('name', 'LIKE', '%-%')->get();

foreach ($models as $model) {
   $model->delete();
}
```

to run delete event for each row so they could be run.

Comment: Doing those extra tasks should be handled by Laravel's Eloquent events.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between `Model::where('name', 'LIKE', '%-%')->delete();` and  `Model::where('name', 'like %-%')->delete();` ?

Answer (score -2):

Can you not just do simple SQL? Pretty common db admin task...

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%-%' ;
```

No looping or PHP required

Comment: There can be benefits to doing it at the PHP level. Laravel's models may have soft deletion enabled, so `delete()` may actually not delete the row but instead flag it as deleted. Models may also have deletion events to handle other cleanup/notification tasks.

Comment: Sure there is but as post said this is a throw away task so sounded like a data maintenance task. Unless soft deletes are setup,  for a one off task,  the sql way is better